# login in partial view is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a login on a partial view without the need to refresh the whole browser when someone logs in.

The login controller works perfectly and also it selects ok the partial View that it has to be shown later. The problem is that this partial View doesn't detect that the user is logged.

If I refresh the web (F5) I can see the user is, as I said, well logged.

Controler:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login() {
    return PartialView("_Login");
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {               
        if(WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe.Value)) {
            return PartialView("LogOnPartialView", "Shared");                    
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Partial View _login

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "loginControl" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
    </div>

      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
}
```

Partial View LogOnPartialView

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  <div>user is logged</div>
}
else
{
    <div>user is NOT logged</div>
}

@if(!Request.IsAuthenticated) 
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Registro", "Register", "Account") 
    @: | 
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Login" })
}
else 
{
    @: Welcome <b>@User.Identity.Name</b>!

    @: |
    @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "LogOff", "Account")
}
```

Could anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: try `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` instead of `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` ?

Comment: Both are the same. Just in case I have tried and it still dosn't work. Ty anyway.

Comment: Few developers use custom `IdentityPrinciple`, So was just checking luck if that was the case in your application... is it forms mode of authentication?

Comment: Form mode:  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>´

Comment: So what does the `WebSecurity.Login` method do? Have you done the `FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);`

Comment: I have used SimpleMembership and WebSecurity.Login() is the function that proceed the login.

Comment: When you login using and ajax request, all the next requests will be authenticated, so surely the login using ajax request and partial view will work and all links which needs authentication will work for the user. Just keep in mind, after you logged in using the ajax request, it doesn't change the appearance of your page and while the user is logged in, since you don't refresh the whole page you will see the same state in your page and for example if some links were not visible before login, they are still invisible and if you need to show them, you need to reload some parts as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you are going to get this working in its current form. If you read [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.login(v=vs.111).aspx) it states

> When a user is logged in, ASP.NET sets an authentication token in a cookie that lets ASP.NET know *on subsequent requests* that the user has been logged in.

Notice the use of the term 'subsequent requests'.
The problem with using it in the same request is the incoming request has *not* sent the auth cookie and thus `IsAuthenticated` is false.
i.e.

1. Browser submits `Login`
2. Server responds with `Set-Cookie`
3. Browser sends this cookie (the auth cookie) on the *next* request

This is the reason it works when you hit F5

What you can do to resolve this is take the result of the call to `WebSecurity.Login` which indicates whether the user logged in successfully and *pass* it to your `LogOnPartialView`

Comment: That is a solution. Effectively I can pass the result of the call to `WebSecurity.Login` And get the `true/false` value in the view. But the PartialView still down't know the user name and sometimes it doesn't refresh correctly, so I think the best solution would be to make the login the usual way with a total page refresh. Anyway ty for your answer, I'll mark it as valid. Enjoy the rep :)

Comment: In 21 hours I will give You the bounty. I can't sooner.

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez you could pass the username to the view model too...however i see no issue with a page reload either... if you really want to have it work without a page reload your view doesnt look too complex... you could simply have your `Login` method update  the relevant section of the page using javascript (assuming it succeeded)